# Could not load file or assembly Of Sqlie on thin Client with xp embeded

Tags: sqlite, c#-4.0, system.data.sqlite

I have a windows application that created with c# 2010.I use Sqlie as a database.
I installed it on thin client with windows xp 2002 embeded.
when I run the application I get the error that "Could not load file or assembly Of System.Data.Sqlie"
What should Id do?